# How to add /.well-known/openid-configuration route in startup.cs along with controller routes and angular routes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am creating a login server using Identityserver4. I am using ASP.net core 3.1 for functionality, and angular 9 project for serving static files for login/registeration screens. The angular project is being served from within the .netcore project's wwwroot folder.

For making sure that my angular routes work properly along with the controller routes, I have added the following in my Startup.cs

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors(Constants.Constants.Policy);
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseIdentityServer();


        app.UseWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/Account"), builder =>
        {
            builder.Use(async (context, next) => {
                await next();
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
                {
                        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                        await next();
                }
            })
            .UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions { DefaultFileNames = new List<string>{"index.html"}})
            .UseStaticFiles();
        });

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
             endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                 name: "default",
                 pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

This ensures that when url contains http://localhost:port/Account/Login It will be served via controller route. Rest every other URL path will be served via angular.

The problem arises when the client applications try to access the http://localhost:port/.well-known/openid-configuration url to get discovery documents. Since, the URL does not start with "Account", it is being served via angular i.e, it gets redirected to the index.html page.

How do I add the **.well-known/openid-configuration** route to my Startup.cs so that it returns the discovery document?

The error I get when accessing IdentityServer from my client app is [image]

The error I get on IdentityServer webpage is

[image]

Comment: I have used app.UseIdentityServer() middleware in  Startup.cs. It somehow got missed when copying the code here. Encountering the same problem even with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add an exception to route /.well-known along with /Account

```
app.UseWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/Account") && !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/.well-known/openid-configuration") , builder =>
        {
            builder.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                    await next();
                }
            })
                .UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions { DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index.html" } })
                .UseStaticFiles();
        });
```